# form_for when updating fails, though creation works?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model, `Disc`.

The `Disc#new` action passes `@disc = Disc.new` to a view that has a simple `form_for` helper, reading

```
form_for(:disc, url: {action: 'create'}) do |f|
  # the usual text fields etc follow
```

In `discs_controller.rb`, I have a private method `disc_params`, which reads `params.require(:disc).permit(:owner, :title)` and so on. `Disc#create` simply says `Disc.create(disc_params)`.

That all works totally fine. Where I run into trouble is creating the edit form.

`Disc#edit` reads `@disc = Disc.find(params[:id])`. The `edit` view is an exact clone of the `new` view, only its opening line reads `form_for(:disc, url: {action: 'update', id: @disc.id})`. It submits to `Disc#update`, which reads `Disc.find(params[:id]).update(disc_params)`.

This seems to me like it should work, but evidently I'm wrong, as it throws the following error: **param is missing or the value is empty: disc**.

The trace points to these two lines:

```
params.require(:disc).permit(:owner_id, :title, :contents)
```

and

```
Disc.find(params[:id]).update(disc_params)
```

This one's stumping me. I'd appreciate if someone could clarify why this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using this:

```
form_for(:disc, url: {action: 'create'}) do |f|
form_for(:disc, url: {action: 'update', id: @disc.id}) do |f|
```

Just provide an instance of `Disc` model:

```
form_for @disc do |f|
```

It surely should eliminate you errors (generate correct url and method) and also gives you an opportunity to use the same form for `new` and `edit` actions.

Answer (score -1):

I think you don't need to do extra stuff just change form like this:

```
form_for @disc do |f|
  #your fields
end
```

Comment: What is the point of giving the same answer after 20+ minutes? I just don't get the idea, no offense.